# Node/Express send static file on request

Tags: node.js, express

I'm really new to node/express and I'm trying to understand how sending static files work. I managed to serve my index file, but I cannot serve other files as response of a GET request.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build')))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '.', 'client/build/', 'index.html'))
  res.end()
})

app.get('/portfolio', (req, res) => {
  const person = req.query.name
  var filePath = __dirname + '/client/build/' + person + '/' + 'index.html'
  res.sendFile(filePath)
  res.end()
})
```

I found similar questions but nothing seems to work.

The request I send is:

```
fetch(`portfolio?name=${who}`)
```

Comment: What request do you send to the server?

Comment: what is `person` and what request are you sending to the server? @alexmac

Comment: I edited the question, the request is 

      fetch(`portfolio?name=${who}`)

where 'who' is a name (string) of the portfolio owner

Answer (score 5):

There's a few problems with your code. One of them is that you end the request before the file is even done sending and another problem is that you're not using the `res.sendFile` method properly.

try something like this:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const fileDirectory = path.resolve(__dirname, '.', 'client/build/');

  res.sendFile('index.html', {root: fileDirectory}, (err) => {
    res.end();

    if (err) throw(err);
  });
})

app.get('/portfolio', (req, res) => {
  const person = req.query.name
  const fileDirectory = __dirname + '/client/build/' + person + '/';

  res.sendFile('index.html', {root: fileDirectory}, (err) => {
    res.end();

    if (err) throw(err);
  });
})
```

I don't recommend throwing an error whenever you get one but it should at least give you an idea how you can get this to work.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. As someone pointed out, the first request handler ('/') is not necessary because express.static maps the routes. But the second one still doesn't work, if I put a console.log it does log something so the request is being processed, but it doesn't do anything nor it throws the error

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it by using this on the server:

```
app.use( express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build/person1')))
app.use( express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build/person2')))
```

and calling it in the view like this:

```
<a href='/person1'></a>
<a href='/person2'></a>
```

As it seems, express.static resolves the paths on its own, so you don't need to handle the request yourself to serve the static files.

If this is not a good solution please coment